# Length cannot be resolved or is not a field (ArrayList get function)

Tags: string, arraylist, field

My code looks like this:

```
private ArrayList<Action> Actions;
private String Action;

Actions.get(Actions.length-1).getString();
```

I keep getting an error on this last line (length cannot be resolved or is not a field). At the moment this is what my method looks like and I can't really proceed because of this error :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using an ArrayList so you need to use size() not length().

Also, since it is a variable it should start with lower case: 'actions'. Otherwise people will mistake it for a Class. You can find more here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

If your question has been answered please ticket the check next to my post to let people know this problem has been solved. Spend some time to read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to learn how this works and welcome!